# Lambda if statement problems

Tags: python, lambda

here is the code:

```
(lambda a,b,c,d,operator: ((lambda a,b,c:((c) if (a == b)))(a,b,c)) if (operator == "aebc") else (((lambda a,b,c:((c) if (a != b)))(a,b,c)) if (operator == "anebc") else (((lambda a,b,c:((c) if (a <= b)))(a,b,c)) if (operator == "alebc") else (((lambda a,b,c:((c) if (a < b)))(a,b,c)) if (operator == "albc") else (((lambda a,b,c:((c) if (a >= b)))(a,b,c)) if (operator == "agebc") else (((lambda a,b,c:((c) if (a > b)))(a,b,c)) if (operator == "agbc") else (((lambda a,b,c,d:((c) if (a == b) else (d)))(a,b,c,d)) if (operator == "aebced") else (((lambda a,b,c,d:((c) if (a != b) else (d)))(a,b,c,d)) if (operator == "anebced") else (((lambda a,b,c,d:((c) if (a <= b) else (d)))(a,b,c,d)) if (operator == "alebced") else (((lambda a,b,c,d:((c) if (a < b) else (d)))(a,b,c,d)) if (operator == "albced") else (((lambda a,b,c,d:((c) if (a >= b) else (d)))(a,b,c,d)) if (operator == "agebced") else (((lambda a,b,c,d:((c) if (a > b) else (d)))(a,b,c,d)) if (operator == "agbced")))))))))))))()
```

I'm making a one-liner for "easy" if statements, to be used in other one-liners. However, I am getting multiple *invalid syntax* errors. How might I fix this, or is there a fundamental problem with this code?

Comment: that hardly looks "easy".

Comment: that is not readable

Comment: You probably have some parentheses misplaced. But I'll be damned if I'm going to try to decipher that mess.

Comment: Unless you're playing Code Golf or entering an obfuscated code contest, there's no prize for squeezing as much onto a single line. Use lambdas and conditional expressions only for short expressions.

Comment: `(c) if (a == b)` doesn't make sense. It sounds like it should be: `c if (a == b) else xxx`

Comment: Please *do not* attempt to force things into one-liners. One liners are only used when a statement is very simple and requires only one line. If a statement is complex trying to fit it in one line will only make it more difficult to work with.

Comment: You have 24 `if` but only 17 `else`. They need to match.

Comment: I'm morbidly curious about what code it is that this lambda would make easier if it worked.  I've got a hunch that this is an XY problem where the thing this lambda is supposed to be doing could be done with a simple existing builtin.

Comment: *"...or is there a fundamental problem with this code?"* - yes. Its length is 989...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks heavy, why not use regular functions?
At first glance, one of the problems is the incorrect use of the ternary operator.
You need use this:

```
c if a == b else some_value
```

Use it so wrong:

```
c if a == b
```